# AWS Cognito / Gatway API call fails on iOS restoration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a Swift app using AWS Gateway API and AWS Cognito.
It uses AWS iOS SDK 2.4.9.

Most of the time my app authenticates and can successfully retrieve content from my AWS service.

However, if restoration is run after a number of dormant hours I see the following:

- the app successfully resumes its AWS Cognito session
- but a call to a Gateway API reports:

  Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSAPIGatewayErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={HTTPBody={
  entries =>

  0 : X-Cache = {contents = "Error from cloudfront"}

  1 : Content-Type = {contents = "application/json"}

  2 : x-amzn-ErrorType = {contents = "InvalidSignatureException"}

  3 : x-amzn-RequestId = {contents = "8495fa1c-a737-11e6-83d0-31533a047a70"}

  4 : Via =

2ebb8]>{contents = "1.1 699f29706ac19519e0b631e243565331.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"}

```
6 : Date = <CFString 0x1742445c0 [0x1ac02ebb8]>{contents = "Thu, 10 Nov 2016 11:19:17 GMT"}

10 : Content-Length = 78

11 : X-Amz-Cf-Id = <CFString 0x174095db0 [0x1ac02ebb8]>{contents = "AlLCIYF8SYXUt2xV4yMdzmQw6t_5ykLBLjN1zE4eOxNgmfo91RySfQ=="}

12 : Connection = <CFString 0x174220560 [0x1ac02ebb8]>{contents = "keep-alive"}
```

}}

If I try iOS SDK 2.4.11 then the error messages changes to:

```
message = "Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'. ";
```

}, HTTPHeaderFields={type = immutable dict, count = 9,

```
"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17405b210 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)/MY_APIG_FUNCTION, NSErrorFailingURLKey=(null)/MY_APIG_FUNCTION, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

It's the (null) in both cases that should have a valid value.

I have a class `` for the authentication.

```
class CustomIdentityProviderManager: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {
    var tokens : [NSObject : AnyObject]?

    init(tokens: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        self.tokens = tokens
    }

    @objc func logins() -> AWSTask {
        return AWSTask(result: tokens)
    }
}

class LoginManager {

    var credentialsProvider : AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider?

    init() {
        // Initialize Amazon Cognito service manager with poolId and region type
        self.credentialsProvider =     AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId:Constants.CognitoIdentityPoolId)
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    }

    func completeLogin(token : A0Token, _ profile: A0UserProfile, _ success : () -> (), _ failure : (NSError) -> ()) {
        // After successful Auth0 login perform Amazon login
        doAmazonLogin(token.idToken, success: success, failure)
        // Store profile and token in keychain
        Application.sharedInstance.storeToken(token, profile: profile)
    }

    func doAmazonLogin(idToken: String, success : () -> (), _ failure : (NSError) -> ()) {
        var task: AWSTask?

        // Initialize clients for new idToken
        if self.credentialsProvider?.identityProvider.identityProviderManager == nil || idToken != Application.sharedInstance.retrieveIdToken() {
            let logins = [Constants.CognitoIDPUrl: idToken]
            task = self.initializeClients(logins)
        } else {
            // Use existing clients
            self.credentialsProvider?.invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials()
            task = self.credentialsProvider?.getIdentityId()
        }
        // Make login
        task!.continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if (task.error != nil) {
                failure(task.error!)
            } else {
                // the task result will contain the identity id
                let cognitoId:String? = task.result as? String
                // Store Cognito token in keychain
                 Application.sharedInstance.storeCognitoToken(cognitoId)
                success()
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    func initializeClients(logins: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> AWSTask? {
        let manager = CustomIdentityProviderManager(tokens: logins!)
        self.credentialsProvider?.setIdentityProviderManagerOnce(manager)
        return self.credentialsProvider?.getIdentityId()
    }

    // enhanced Auth0 code to refresh tokenId if it has expired
    func resumeLogin(success : () -> (), _ failure : (NSError) -> ()) {

        let idToken = Application.sharedInstance.retrieveIdToken()
        if let idToken = idToken {
            if Application.sharedInstance.isTokenIdExpired(idToken) {
                let refreshSuccess = {(token:A0Token!) -> () in
                    self.doAmazonLogin(token.idToken, success: success, failure)
                    Application.sharedInstance.storeToken(token)
                    success()
                }

                let refreshFail = {(error:NSError!) -> () in
                    Application.sharedInstance.logout()
                    failure(error)
                }

                if let refreshToken = Application.sharedInstance.retrieveRefreshToken() {
                    A0Lock.sharedLock().apiClient().fetchNewIdTokenWithRefreshToken(refreshToken, parameters: nil, success: refreshSuccess, failure: refreshFail)
                } else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: "com.auth0", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString("Something went wrong", comment: "This is an error")])
                    failure(error)
                }
            } else {
                doAmazonLogin(idToken, success: success, failure)
            }
        } else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "com.auth0", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString("Something went wrong", comment: "This is an error")])
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

On App startup I call resumeLogin(). During a restoration this succeeds but when I try and make a APIG call it can sometimes fail. Particularly after a number of hours after app use.

I call my AWS APIG service like this:

```
let client = XXXXxxxxClient.defaultClient()
client.questionGet().continueWithBlock { …
```

Comment: Can you share the code that related to how you invoke your API?

Comment: Looks like you are not using the generated SDK from API Gateway. May I ask a question since I am not a swift expert? Are you using the Auth0 client (A0Lock) to call API Gateway?

Comment: I'm using Auth0 as an authentication provider but then use AWS Cognito with credentialsProvider?.getIdentityId() to get access to my Identity Pool and my APIG server.

Comment: I am sorry. I might be missing the part you are calling API Gateway. Could you mind pointing it out?

Comment: sorry I missed an example of an APIG from my question. I've now added how I'm calling my APIG to the end of the question.

Comment: I downloaded the Swift SDK from APIG and today it compiles and talks to my AWS Server just fine. Perhaps I was caught out by a earlier bleeding edge release?